# GPMC missing Hide/Show links

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, mmc

We currently have a single 2012 R2 server in our domain.  As we're rolling out Windows 8+ machines I like using it for Group Policy Management.

For some reason the Group Policy Management Console on this server doesn't show the "Show/Hide" links in the Settings tab, so I can't fold and unfold the sections.

[image: GPMC Win2012]

When I hover my mouse over the title bar of a section it turns to the pointing hand as if it's a link I can click, but it does nothing.

The links show and work as expected in the GPMC on our Win2008 R2 servers:

[image: GPMC Win2008]

All systems are up-to-date with Windows/IE updates.

Is there some way I can get the links to show up on the 2012 server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) in Server Manager.

Comment: Or use GPMC remotely from a workstation. Friends don't let friends install GUI on a server.  ;)

Comment: Interesting. It was already disabled.  I enabled and then disabled it again and that fixed it.  Weird.  Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add "about:security_mmc.exe" to the Trusted Sites of Internet Explorer to correct the issue.

Comment: Good idea, but how can this be done by GPO for example?